# OutputStream class for use with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, io, concurrency, stream, child-process

I've recently been writing an application which does a lot of work with the output of commands.  To call the commands I've been using the subprocess module, and originally, was using `subprocess.PIPE`s for the `stdout` and `stderr`, and then using the communicate method once the process was complete to retrieve the output to work with it, log it, etc.  Unfortunately, I had a problem with deadlocks when a particular command generated a long output stream.

For this reason, I've written an `OutputStream` class, an instance of which can be provided as the `stdout` and `stderr` params of `subprocess.Popen`.  In the background, it writes to a `cStringIO` buffer which I can retrieve the value from later, and it seems to work well.  However, this is the first time I've worked with anything like this and I'm concerned that I might be doing something potentially unsafe.  I'd appreciate any feedback anybody has.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import os
import threading

class OutputStream(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OutputStream, self).__init__()
        self.done = False
        self.buffer = StringIO()
        self.read, self.write = os.pipe()
        self.reader = os.fdopen(self.read)
        self.start()

    def fileno(self):
        return self.write

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.buffer.write(self.reader.readline())

        self.reader.close()

    def close(self):
        self.done = True
        os.close(self.write)
```

I would then use it something like this:

```
import subprocess
import time

stream = OutputStream()
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=stream, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

while proc.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.05)

stream.close()
output = stream.buffer.getvalue()
print output
```

Edit: When running the test code above, Python doesn't exit once the command output has been printed.  Such behaviour isn't exhibited by my application in which this class is being used.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about threading to help with that part, but it looks like your class could benefit from implementing the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions that would allow it to be used with the `with` keyword.

There's a [short section in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) about it as well as [an entry in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) from when it was added to Python. `with` allows you to instantiate an object that involves some connection or file that needs to be closed and will always ensure that even if errors arise, the object will be closed accordingly regardless of those errors. It's like wrapping your document with `try: finally: stream.close()`, but without needing to add that every time you call the stream.

Here's how it might look in your object:

```
def __enter__(self):
    # Theoretically could be used to set up things not in __init__
    return self

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.close()
```

The parameters that `__exit__` takes will be passed to it are just exception information, you could use them if you wanted to but they have to be included in the definition as they'll be passed as part of the `with` syntax.

Now you could use the object like this:

```
with OutputStream() as stream:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=stream, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    while proc.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.05)
```